# Migrate data from one server to another

Tags: linux

I bought a new server and I want to move all the data (directories, sub directories, users, passwords, ..etc) from my old server to it.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have physical access to both servers? If so you can use the [dd](http://www.backuphowto.info/linux-backup-hard-disk-clone-dd) command to make a clone of the disk from the old server to the disk that is going into the new server.

In order to do this though, both hard drives have to be installed in one of the servers.

You can also use [netcat](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-copy-compressed-drive-image-over-network.html) and `dd` to clone a disk over a network.

Answer (score 1):

for the directories and files, use a FTP client from your server, if it allows you to, if not, just download all the content to your computer and upload it to the new server.

For the users and passwords, i guess they are in a Database, connect to the database using SSH, telnet, or MysqlAdmin or any RMDB client system and export a dump file, then log in to the new server's SQL system and import that dump file.

Anyway you should give more details of both servers anyway so we can help you, for example, are they Shared hosting or dedicated machine? and what kind of access do you have to them, also, their operative system would help people to reply you accurately

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. They are dedicated servers. The operating system is Liunx-Debian. I am looking for a way that help me to take an image of one server and imported into the other server. if that possible.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, yes.

If the hardware is similar (= just more RAM, disk space but same CPU architecture and no special graphics card drivers), you might be able to copy every file and then install the boot loader once more (the boot loader config usually changes when the hard disk size changes).

Or you can create a list of all services that you use, determine which config files each one uses and then just copy those. Ideally, you shouldn't copy them but compare the old and the new versions and merge them.

The most work intensive way is to use a tool like [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/). In a nutshell, puppet allows to create install scripts for services (along with all the configuration that you need). So if you need to install a service again (new hardware, second server), you just tell puppet to do it. On the plus side, your whole installation will be documented, too. If you ever wonder why something is the way it is, you can look into the puppet files.

Of course, this approach takes a lot of time and discipline, so it might not be worth it in your case. Apply common sense.